# Split string by char in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm getting a string from the web looking like this:

```
Latest Episode@04x22^Killing Your Number^May/15/2009
```

Then I need to store `04x22`, `Killing Your Number` and `May/15/2009` in diffent variables, but it won't work.

```
String[] all = inputLine.split("@");
String[] need = all[1].split("^");
show.setNextNr(need[0]);
show.setNextTitle(need[1]);
show.setNextDate(need[2]);
```

Now it only stores `NextNr`, with the whole string

```
04x22^Killing Your Number^May/15/2009
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`String.split(String regex)`

The argument is a regualr expression, and `^` has a special meaning there; "anchor to beginning"

You need to do:

`String[] need = all[1].split("\\^");`

By escaping the `^` you're saying "I mean the character '^' "

Comment: Splitting on a regular expression is the slowest of them all.
Take a look at Guava's Splitter class.

Comment: Often (or let's say ... always), suggesting that someone include a giant dependency in their project for something that would shave a few nanoseconds which you don't actually care about and wouldn't matter one iota ... isn't exactly good advice. Also see: Premature optimization.

Comment: Guava is a well designed generic library that nicely complements the jre libs. It is not 'giant', nor only useful for this one problem.
BTW, String.split() does compile the regular expression each time it is executed. Using it outside tests and initialization is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 23):

If you have a separator but you don't know if it contains special characters you can use the following approach

```
String[] parts = Pattern.compile(separator, Pattern.LITERAL).split(text);
```

Answer (score 7):

Using guava, you can do it elegantly AND fast:

```
private static final Splitter RECORD_SPLITTER = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("@^")).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();

...

Iterator<String> splitLine = Iterables.skip(RECORD_SPLITTER.split(inputLine), 1).iterator();

show.setNextNr(splitLine.next());
show.setNextTitle(splitLine.next());
show.setNextDate(splitLine.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String[] split(String string, char separator) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < string.length(); index++)
        if (string.charAt(index) == separator)
            count++;
    String parts[] = new String[count];
    int partIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < string.length(); index++)
        if (string.charAt(index) == separator) {
            parts[partIndex++] = string.substring(startIndex, index);
            startIndex = index + 1;
        }
    parts[partIndex++] = string.substring(startIndex);
    return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "Latest Episode@04x22^Killing Your Number^May/15/2009";

//split will work for both @ and ^
String splitArr[] = input.split("[@\\^]");

/*The output will be,
 [Latest Episode, 04x22, Killing Your Number, May/15/2009]
*/
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitArr));
```

Comment: Could you explain _how_ this answers the question?

Comment: String can be split based upon multiple conditions. Here i used @ and ^ to split a string. It both will work as a delimiter and will split the string.