# Regex matching exact instance of special characters

Tags: java, regex

Pardon for asking again the same regex issues but combining all existent answers here doesn't give me good results.

In Java (like "aa | bb ".split(myregex)) I need to split string one time by "|" other time by "||".

Please, note "|" must not match appearance of "||" or "|||". For example, regex of "|" must not touch "aa || bb". But regex of "||" should split all "||"+ like "aa || bb" and "aa |||| bb" as the same.
I tried different variations of  \b(?:([\|])(?!\1))+\b  but this had bad results against online regex checkers.

Please, help. Share with us two those regexes.

Regards,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18252327/493759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two iterations?

```
result1 = myString.split("[^\\|]\\|[^\\|]"); // result of splitting on |, regex means | not followed by another | or preceded
result2 = result1.split("\\|{2,}"); // result of splitting on | that occurs 2 or more times
```

not sure how you should split on odd count of |-es, but if you only need even:

```
result2 = result1.split("(\\|\\|)+"); // result of splitting on || that occur any times
```

Maybe more readable:

```
String not(String s){
  return "[^" + s + "]";
}
String pipe = "\\|";

result1 = myString.split(not(pipe) + pipe + not(pipe)); 
result2 = result1.split(pipe + "{2,}");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(?:(?<!\\|)\\|(?:\\|)|\\|{2,})
```

This will match a pipe not preceeded nor followed by another pipe or a number of pipe greater than or equal to 2.