# How to extract Key Value from String(Char Array) in JAVA

Tags: java, json, string, jackson

Sorry if some one ask this question earlier but I am unable to find relatively.

My query is

String like this -> {"value":123,"key":abc};

Change into =>

```
String str = ['"','v','a','l','u','e',':','1','2','3',',','k','e','y',':','a','b','c','"']; // char array
```

**str[0] will be " , str[1] will be v**

So I want to know whether it is possible if i want to fetch value by this.
let's say

```
str.getString("value") = 123  <- output expecting
```

things i tried:

```
1. JSONObject newStr = (JSONObject)JsonSerializer.toJSON(str);
2. Str.contains("key")
3. JSONObject newStr = new JSONObject(str);
```

but nothing work for me.
Can any one help me with that.

Is there any way so that i can get this answer like this.

*str.get("value") = 123
and str.get("key") = abc*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: You must need to put more efforts to get it done,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string by char in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296445/split-string-by-char-in-java)

Comment: You are receiving char Array or String array?

Comment: @RahulGupta Char array

Answer (score 2):

Maybe updating the first and last element in the char array with `{` and `}` respectively.

Constructing a String from it.

Parsing it in a JSONObject and then you can fetch what you want.

Sample code:

```
        Character[] str = {'{', 'v','a','l','u','e',':','1','2','3',',','k','e','y',':','a','b','c','}'};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length);
        for (Character c : str)
            sb.append(c.charValue());
        String strb = sb.toString();

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(strb);

        System.out.print(obj.get("value"));
```

Output

> 123

Comment: Thanks this can be one of an answer but this one is Brute force, I am looking for some optimise solution or any library..